# Ribs in oven - foil method

Tags: oven, barbecue, ribs

I've seen numerous online recipes for ribs stating to either 1) cover the ribs in foil 2) cover the baking sheet the ribs are on in foil

Which will yield the most tender ribs?

Comment: This sounds like the kind of question where the only answer will be someone's opinion. Which is the best for what? Are you going for a specific texture, technique, ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt you would find a significant difference as long as option 2 means placing the ribs on the pan and putting foil over the ribs...and, it was sealed tightly, but [Meathead Goldwyn](https://amazingribs.com/more-technique-and-science/more-cooking-science/texas-crutch-wrap-foil-tenderize-and-speed-cooking) suggests wrapping the meat itself.  The idea is that you are creating more of a braising environment. The wrap also significantly reduces evaporative cooling from the surface of the meat.  This helps in being able to more consistently predict time until they are done.

Comment: Very similar in effect to Alton Brown's, "Who loves baby back ribs." I've been fully wrapping dry rubbed ribs in ful and roast at 225 for 4-5 hours, reducing the liquid for a baste and then broiling until they're dark enough for me. I haven't had this recipe fail and I've been doing baby backs in the oven since that episode aired many years ago.